# UV islands won't align correctly

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm having issues with unwrapping a mesh with no seams. It should be a very easy process but I've been trying to solve this issue for a couple of hours.

[image: image of the buggy unwrap. Green is highlighting the correct sections and Red highlights the incorrect]
[image: UV in question]

As you can see from the images above, it results in a horrible alignment. No double vertices, all transformations applied... The only parts that unwrap correctly are the furthest left faces and the bottom face. I have no idea why the rest of the UV won't align. Cube projection seems to get around this issue but it results in warped faces and unaccounted for UVs.

Did I unwrap this mesh correctly? If not, why isn't it unwrapping properly?

[image]

Comment: why have you separated the UVs? Maybe select all the mesh and unwrap once?

Comment: It's all part of the same object, they were unwrapped together.

Comment: it doesn't look like, the UVs are separated as we can see in the UV Editor, it explains why the texture doesn't match

Comment: maybe provide your blend file so we can check it out?

Comment: i added the blend file... cheers for the help!

Comment: moonboots got is quicker ;) but as you can see - providing blend files help a lot to get quicker and more precise answers ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The first part of the object is disconnected from the second part.You just need to join it.
like this**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in *Edit* mode the faces are separate, it separates the UVs when you unwrap:

[image]

You can quickly fix your problem if you create this edge and merge it with this vertex, then unwrap again:

[image]

Or choose another unwrap method, like *Project From View*.